# Kohana 3.1 - how to name controller with dash (-)

Tags: url, routes, kohana-3

I'm working with Kohana 3.1 and this is my problem:

I want to make controller that is named like this: Controller_my-controller so I can have URL like this http://example.org/my-controller

How can I do something like this?
Some routing or maybe some type of class that changes naming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible as Kohana Controller is a PHP class and you need to follow PHP class naming conventions. But you can write a Route with function that can remove (-) from controller name before Kohana will search for mycontroller not my-controller. [documentation](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/routing)